# textarea where part of the text can be moved but NOT deleted

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, textarea

[image]

Above is generally what I'm trying to create. There has to be a piece of text which is always in the textarea. It can be dragged to a different part of the text area, but it can never be deleted. You can type both before it and after it.

I've been trying to find the best approach to accomplish this for several days and have come up short. Anyone ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A start , using `contentEditable` parent element , `div` having `input type="text"` element with `disabled` attribute set to `"true"` . `TODO:` Drag and Drop adjustments ; currently only utilizes `.appendChild` to drop `div` containing `input` to parent `div` , without placing `draggable` element between editable text in parent `contentEditable` `div`

```css
input {
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div[droppable="true"] {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div[draggable="true"] {
  width: 250px;
}
div[draggable="true"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function dragstartHandler(e) {
    // add `input` element's name to the data transfer object
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.firstElementChild.name);
  }

  function dropHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the `name` of the target and add the moved element to the target's DOM
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    e.target.appendChild(
      document.querySelector("input[name=" + data + "]").parentElement
    );
  }

  document.ondragover = function(event) {
    // prevent default to allow drop
    // TODO: drop `input` parent `div` element between `contentEditable` text
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event)
  };
</script>

<div contentEditable="true" droppable="true" ondrop="dropHandler(event);">
  This text can be edited
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstartHandler(event);">
    <input disabled name="fixed" type="text" 
           minlength="14" maxlength="14" value="BUT THIS CAN'T" />
  </div>and so can this one here

</div>
```

Comment: Great start! That's further along than I've been able to get... However my problem with this answer is that the "BUT THIS CAN'T" text can still be deleted, which is one of the biggest things I was trying to avoid